# How do I Construct a list on the fly and pass it as a method parameter?

Tags: java, arrays, list

I have a a method like this :

```
List < Object > getObjects(List<Integer> ids)
```

I want to construct a list on the fly (as a parameter) using an integer (say some int a) instead of creating and storing a list in a local variable and then passing it.

```
List<Integer> intList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
intList.add(a);
getObjects(intList)
```

How do i do this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can either use [`Arrays.asList()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList(T...)):

```
getObjects(Arrays.asList(a));
```

or [`Collections.singletonList()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#singletonList(T)) if you have only one value (faster and more compact):

```
getObjects(Collections.singletonList(a));
```

Tip: consider static imports:

```
import static java.util.Arrays.asList;
import static java.util.Collections.singletonList;

getObjects(asList(a));
getObjects(singletonList(a));
```

Answer (score 2):

This is how you would pass it.

```
getObjects(Arrays.asList(a)).
```

[Java Reference for Arrays.asList()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList%28T...%29)